# Using JavaScript which of these code chunks is best for real world use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is just an example but there are a bunch of similar scenarios sprinkled throughout the code so it would be nice to choose the best solution and stick with it. The first is probably quickier but the second takes up less space*

*less space when reading/fixing code and less space when downloading.

```
if (imageCountCurrent <= 0){
    $('#next_arrow').addClass('disabled');
}
else{
    $('#next_arrow').removeClass('disabled');
}
if (imageCountCurrent >= imageCount - 5){
    $('#prev_arrow').addClass('disabled');
}
else{
    $('#prev_arrow').removeClass('disabled');
}



$('#.arrow').removeClass('disabled');
if (imageCountCurrent <= 0){
    $('#next_arrow').addClass('disabled');
}
if (imageCountCurrent >= imageCount - 5){
    $('#prev_arrow').addClass('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want `.toggleClass` instead, which eliminates the need for verbose `if`/`else` and `addClass`/`removeClass` constructs:

```
$('#next_arrow').toggleClass('disabled', imageCountCurrent <= 0);
$('#prev_arrow').toggleClass('disabled', imageCountCurrent >= imageCount - 5);
```

Comment: I agree but try to ignore the syntax and assume it's doing something else. Is it better to do the assignment to reset them all and then reassign if needed or do if/elses?

Comment: @Ryan Detzel: I have to say that's a little bit vague, but if the code is not doing something expensive then option #2 has my preference. But if you're resetting a lot you may find a performance decrease.